# com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed

Tags: java, spring-mvc, networking, network-programming, cassandra-2.0

Im facing the below issue when trying to connect to cassandra cluster and display table contents:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /175.14.3.164:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.TransportException: [/172.16.3.163:9042] Cannot connect))
at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.reconnectInternal(ControlConnection.java:223)
at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.connect(ControlConnection.java:78)
at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.init(Cluster.java:1272)
at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.init(Cluster.java:158)
at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connect(Cluster.java:248)
at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connect(Cluster.java:281)
at com.X.Y.App.main(App.java:27)
```

In my cassandra.yaml file

```
native_transport_port: 9042
My listen_address : 172.14.3.164
seeds: 172.14.3.164
rpc_address: 172.14.3.164
```

And code :

```
cluster=Cluster.builder().addContactPoint("172.14.3.164").build();
```

I had seen other links related to it but followed them but still could n't fix it. Kindly help

Comment: Please show us that Cassandra is up and running.

Comment: I ran sudo service cassandra start and it says cassandra is up and running

Comment: Attempt to telnet to that address and port.

Comment: Hi Sotirious i fixed this issue by checking my logs.Changed my cluster name back to 'test cluster' and issue got resolved automatically.. and thanks for your replies